# Array bound error catching

Tags: c++, arrays, error-handling

I have a binary search tree class that we are required to implement with a static array.  My instructor requires us to do error handling for the insert and delete functions.  I am trying to throw an error from the overloaded [] operator and catch it in the insert function, then throw it to the main function.   My BST holds positive integers; -1 is used to signify an empty node.

overloaded [] operators

```
//overloaded [] operator to perform bounds checking of the array and return the value associated to the index
int& BST::operator[](int i)
{
    if(i < 0 || i >= BST_SIZE)
    {
        throw out_of_range("ERROR: BST has reached maximum depth");
    }
    else
    {
        return Tree[i];
    }
}

//overloaded [] operator to perform bounds checking of the array and return the value associated to the index and also
//allows BST manipulation
const int& BST::operator[](int i) const
{
    if(i < 0 || i >= BST_SIZE)
    {
        throw out_of_range("ERROR: BST has reached maximum depth");
    }
    else
    {
        return Tree[i];
    }
}
```

insert functions

```
//insert function called by main to insert a valid value into the BST
void BST::insert(const int& x)
{
    if(Tree[0] == -1)
    {
        Tree[0] = x;
    }
    else if(Tree[0] > x)
    {
        insert(x, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        insert(x, 2);
    }
}

//recursive insert function called by insert function with one arguement to move through BST
void BST::insert(const int& x, const int& loc)
{
    try
    {
        Tree[loc];                //used to cause throw from [] operator is necessary
    }
    catch(out_of_range& e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
    if(Tree[loc] == -1)           //ERROR-> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x7fff5fcfd7b4)
    {
        Tree[loc] = x;
    }
    else if(Tree[loc] > x)
    {
        insert(x, (2*loc)+1);
    }
    else
    {
        insert(x, (2*loc)+2);
    }
}
```

main function snippet containing code usage

```
BST myTree;
try
{
    myTree.insert(6);
    myTree.insert(2);
    myTree.insert(4);
    myTree.insert(0);
    myTree.insert(9);
    myTree.insert(3);
    myTree.insert(8);
    myTree.insert(76);
    myTree.insert(1);
    myTree.insert(5);
    myTree.insert(99);
    myTree.insert(101);
    myTree.insert(999);
    myTree.insert(11010);
    myTree.insert(6859);
    myTree.insert(9956);
    myTree.display();
}
catch(out_of_range& e)
{
    cout << e.what() << endl;
    exit(2);
}
```

Currently my code will compile and run when the BST does not try to insert a new value when full.  Right now I am trying to overfill my BST and catch the error to ensure the error handling works. I am using Xcode 7.2 and getting the commented error above in place where it occurs in the second insert function.  It seems to me like the IDE is throwing an error before mine is thrown.

Comment: In your `try` block I assume `Tree[loc]` is not calling your overloaded operator. You want something like `this->operator[](loc);`.

Comment: Thank you! I see what I was screwing up.

Comment: Suggestion -- you don't need the `else` in your overloaded `[ ]`.  `if(i < 0 || i >= BST_SIZE)   throw out_of_range("ERROR: BST has reached maximum depth"); return Tree[i]; }`

Comment: If it makes sense for your code, you could consider moving `Tree` and the overloaded `[]` operators into another class and using that inside `BST`. Then you can index it "naturally" and catch any thrown exceptions outside the call to `insert`, as you do in `main`.